# Stored procedure looking for part categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a stored procedure that looks for part categories. They always started with M historically, but we have parts now beginning S that don't appear in the data.

I want to look for M and S, so in the below procedure how do I change it to look for both Where Left(CS_REF,1) ='M'?

I'm not a programmer...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CatTypes] AS
 SELECT LEFT(CS_REF,3) AS Cat
 FROM a_cstwh
 WHERE LEFT(CS_REF,1) = 'M'
 GROUP BY LEFT(CS_REF,3)
 ORDER BY LEFT(CS_REF,3)
 OPTION (HASH GROUP)
```

Comment: Why the GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used?

Comment: do I put it exactly as you have so its, WHERE LEFT(CS_REF,1) = IN ('M', 'S')

Comment: hi jarlh, im not a programmer so have no idea, im just trying to get the parts to show that begin with S, the program was written about 12 years ago so im pretty sure a lot of it is old school

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, as a note it looks like there must be other areas that its hard coded to look for parts only starting With M as it wont show parts starting S, they are not in the sql so must be in the program itself so had to change them to start with M in database

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT LEFT(CS_REF,3) AS Cat
FROM a_cstwh
WHERE LEFT(CS_REF,1) IN ('M', 'S')
GROUP BY LEFT(CS_REF,3)
ORDER BY LEFT(CS_REF,3)
OPTION (HASH GROUP)
```

(OR)

```
SELECT LEFT(CS_REF,3) AS Cat
FROM a_cstwh
WHERE LEFT(CS_REF,1) = 'M' OR LEFT(CS_REF,1) =  'S'
GROUP BY LEFT(CS_REF,3)
ORDER BY LEFT(CS_REF,3)
OPTION (HASH GROUP)
```